# Авторизация ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

Есть такая проблема, если логин и пароль не правильный, то в блоке выводит неправильный логин и пароль, но если правильный, то в этом же блоке, появляется дубликат сайта, почему так, если в php коде, я написал переадресацию?

```
<p>Вход на сайт</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><label><span>Логин</span><input class="login" name="login" type="text"></label></div>
        <div><label><span>Пароль</span><input class="password" name="password" type="password"></label></div>

        <input type="submit" class="auth" name="auth" value="Войти">
    </form>

    <div id="wrongLogin"></div>

<div class="registr"><a href="?action=registr">Или зарегистрируйтесь</div>

<script>
    var auth = document.querySelector('.auth');
        auth.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var forma = e.target.parentElement;
            var login = forma.elements.login.value;
            var pass = forma.elements.password.value;

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                    wrongLogin.innerHTML=this.responseText;
                }
            }

                xmlhttp.open("POST","./",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                xmlhttp.send("log="+login+"&password="+pass);               
            })              


</script>
```

php файл

```
function login($login, $password) {

        $newLogin = str_replace(";","",$login);
        $newLogin2 = str_replace(")","",$newLogin);
        $newLogin3 = str_replace("'","",$newLogin2);

        $sqlPass = "SELECT `id`, `login`, `password`, `avatar`, `link_vk`, `reputation` FROM users WHERE login = :log";
        $resPass = $this->db->prepare($sqlPass);
        $resPass->bindValue(':log', trim($newLogin3), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $resPass->execute();

        $allRes = $resPass->fetchAll();


        if(count($allRes) == 0) {
            die('<p>Неверный логин или пароль</p>');
        }

        $needPassword = $allRes[0]['password'];
        $userId = $allRes[0]['id'];
        $userLogin = $allRes[0]['login'];
        $userAvatar = $allRes[0]['avatar'];
        $userVk = $allRes[0]['link_vk'];
        $userRep =$allRes[0]['reputation'];


        $hash = $needPassword;

        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {

            $salt = 'slovo';
            $tokenstr = strval(date('s')) . $salt;
            $token = md5($tokenstr);

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET token ='" . $token . "' WHERE login = :log2";
            $queryToket = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $queryToket->bindValue(':log2', trim($newLogin3), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $queryToket->execute();

            setcookie ("user", $token, time()+604800);

            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $userLogin;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $userAvatar;
            $_SESSION['vkontakte'] = $userVk;
            $_SESSION['reputation'] = $userRep;
            output_add_rewrite_var('token', $token);
            header('Location: ./index.php?token='.$_SESSION['token']);

        }

        else {
            die('<p>Неверный логин или пароль</p>');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы переадресуете запрос который вы отправляете аяксом, поэтому то у вас и отображает дубликат сайта. Вам нужно сделать примерно следующее

При верном логине вместо

```
header('Location: ./index.php?token='.$_SESSION['token']);
```

нужно проставлять статус 200, хотя он и по умолчанию будет 200

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

а вот вместо

```
die('<p>Неверный логин или пароль</p>');
```

отправлять

```
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

а в js уже соответственно ловить

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            window.location.reload(false);
        }
        else {
            wrongLogin.innerHTML='<p>Неверный логин или пароль</p>';
        }
    }
};
```