# Как остановить регистрацию без перехода на другую станицу?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (empty($login) or empty($password)){
exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}
```

Comment: Я PHP только недавно начал учить и если у вас есть вопросы к моему вопросу(ха-ха), то я могу ответить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692804/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ajax-php

Comment: и другие [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+%5Bphp%5D+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так или иначе некий "переход" всё равно будет. Можно только попытаться скрыть его от пользователя, например, ajax'ом. Но для понимания механизма работы достаточно рассмотреть простой пример:

```
// предположим, это некий файл с формой регистрации form.php
$params = [];
if (!empty($_GET['error'])) {
    if ($_GET['error'] == 'empty_login') {
        $params['show_error_empty_login'] = true;
    }
}
echo render('шаблон_формы.tpl', $params);
```

Файл `form.php` просто выводит html-страницу с формой. Форма сабмитится на адрес `join.php` (он ниже). Если страница формы запрашивается с аргументом `?error=empty_login`, то в шаблон добавляется флаг `show_error_empty_login=true` по которому вы можете вывести на форме текст ошибки.

```
// а это сама регистрация в системе, join.php
if (empty($_POST['login'])) {
    header('Location: /form.php?error=empty_login');
    exit;
}
DB::insert("запрос на регистрацию нового юзера");
header('Location: /index.php');
```

Второй файл принимает поля формы POST'ом, проверяет их и регистрирует пользователя. Если поле логина пустое (другие поля добавьте аналогично), то происходит редирект - возврат назад на форму, но в адресной строке дописывается параметр, который укажет форме, что произошла ошибка. Иначе, если ошибки нет, будет создан новый пользователь и редирект на главную страницу сайта. Этот редирект в конце тоже нужен обязательно чтобы предотвратить повторные попытки создать такого же пользователя, если пользователь после сабмита формы будет жать F5 и обновлять страницу - запросы будут снова лететь в файл регистрации, поэтому прокидываем пользователя на главную (или куда вам нужно).

Теперь можно усложнить скрипты, добавить сохранение значений в полях между страницами на случай, если часть полей заполнена верно, а часть нет и надо дозаполнить форму. При редиректе значения потеряются, придётся где-то их временно хранить, в куках или сессии или даже прямо в адресной строке.

Плюс можно ещё усложнить процесс, не делать сабмита и редиректов, а слать значения полей формы ajax'ом, проверять их на клиенте с помощью JS и принимать решения на этом. Нет предела совершенству!